# Java: Zipinputstream to Zipoutputstream leads to "end-of-central-directory signature not found" Error

Tags: java, zipinputstream, zipoutputstream

I try to copy a Zip from a `Zipinputstream` to a `Zipoutputstream`.

I store the Zip as `byte[]` in a Oracle database. I use `Zipinputstream` to decompress the zip (later I want to edit the Zip) and then put it into a `Zipoutputstream` to get a new `byte[]` and use this array to download the file later via a `ServletOutputStream`. When I create a new file - without the `Zipinputstream` - it works. But when I use the `Zipinputstream` I get the error.

Here is my code:

```
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileFromDataBase),
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        ZipEntry currentEntry;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((currentEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(currentEntry.getName());
            zos.putNextEntry(newEntry);
            int length;
            while ((length = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();                   
        }

        //TO Object to download later the Zipfile from html page
        paketDownloadTO = new PaketDownloadTO();
        paketDownloadTO.setData(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        paketDownloadTO.setFileName(fileName);

        zos.finish();
        zipInputStream.close();
        zos.close();
```

Comment: Why? Just copy the bytes. You don't need all this complication.

Comment: Because I later need to edit the zip (put new files into, delete some etc) But if plain copy is not working, then I cant edit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that You should do `zos.close()` before `byteArrayOutputStream.close()`.

UPDATE:

and move:

```java
paketDownloadTO = new PaketDownloadTO();
paketDownloadTO.setData(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
paketDownloadTO.setFileName(fileName);
```

after `zos.close();`

Comment: In fact *instead of* `ByteArrayOutputStream.close()` which is redundant if a stream wrapping it has been closed.

Comment: Both do not fix the problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, calling `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` before calling `zipInputStream.close()`

The ZipInputStream only write the end-of-central-directory when close is called, because before that it does not know if you're going to add new entries or not.

But since `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` returns a copy of the byte array at the time you're calling it. It does not contains the end-of-central-directory, which is written to the stream at a later time.